# Android how to pass google account to webview

Tags: android, webview, google-calendar-api, account

I am using webview to show google canlender but want to pass google account programmatic-ally,so the setHttpAuthUsernamePassword() function should be what I need but it doesn't work at all. Here is the code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("www.google.com", "", "email", "password");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override 
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest (WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host,String realm){ 
            handler.proceed("email","password"); 
            }
        } 

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/calendar/");
```

If you have any idea to make this worked, please let me know. I tried to search a lot but don't see any useful.

Comment: I think this will never work, because even using google api java client we still need user input for authorization. Check out here http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html. Please correct me if ....

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use HTTP authentication (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which is not supported by most web services.  You need to have valid Google cookies, which are set only when you manually sign in with your password.